# Is that possible to make Finder.app to highlight/select newly pasted file(s)?

Tags: finder

I am running macOS Big Sur 11.4.

In other operating systems, when you paste new files in file manager, the newly added/pasted files will be highlighted and selected. This is really important and convenient when the current folder/directory has many files. I can find the newly pasted file(s) easily.

But in Finder.app, it doesn't do it. It selects/highlights no file after pasting action.

Is that possible to achieve this in macOS?

I don't want to memorize those filename(s) and find newly pasted file(s) from thousands of files.

Comment: Not a solution but workaround: add column 'Date added' to Finder and sort by it. This way pasted files will always be on top.

Comment: It's not new to Big Sur. The Mac has never highlighted newly-generated files of any sort. If you already have a selection before the paste, that selection is preserved.

Comment: If it's a specific set of folders, you can make an AppleScript Folder Action that will automatically select newly added files. Would that work for you?

Comment: Presumably, you copy and paste these files, and then do something else with them. It might be useful to know what you plan to do with the files after pasting them. There may be another method of achieving the complete process without going through this individual step.

Comment: First, thanks all for your comments. @AivarPaalberg : thank you for your workaround.  Sorting by 'Date added' is much better than searching for the filenames.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for your comment. I have different plans in different situations. I always want to do something on newly pasted file(s). Eg: (1) I might want to rename the file after pasting it. (2) I might want to open the file with some app after pasting the file. (3) I might want to select it and copy as path name (4) I might want to find which position it goes when sorting by name. There are different sub-cases. I might do something to the file before or after this file in position etc. (5) make alias etc. There might be something else I might do but I don't recall so far. Cheers.

Comment: @sgon00 You'll forgive me for pursuing this line of questioning, but if you've got several folders, each with 'thousands of files', and you're regularly duplicating files between them -- are you sure that's the most effective organisation?

Comment: @benwiggy no worries, you can ask any questions. I am NOT regularly duplicating files between them. There are many situations. Not each with thousands of files. For instance, It can be one folder with a few files and copy one file from it to a folder which has thousands of files. That is a copy case. For another case, It can be Cut/Paste. Cut/Paste with CMD+ALT+V when pasting. In such case, there is NO duplicating at all.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a series of AppleScript droplets: AppleScript applications that you can drag-drop files onto so they can be processed in various ways. Either that, or a bunch of Finder services (will fill roughly the same role. Cutting and pasting files is a very 'Windows' way of doing things; the Finder will do it, but there's a lot more built-in support for drag-drop.

Comment: @TedWrigley thanks for your comments. Sorry that I don't know how to write applescript. I  just want the newly pasted files to be selected. That's all. I don't really need any extra work (I don't need to process the files in various ways). I am wondering if there is any online applescript which can acheive what I want. Just to clarify one more time. I just want newly pasted files to be selected in FInder.app. (Btw, I don't really use 'Windows' at all. That's why I used "other operating systems" in the question instead of 'Windows'.)

Comment: @sgon00: I'll add an answer that will do what you want, no big problem. I'm merely suggesting that what you *want* is maybe not what you *ought* to want. There's a lot you can do to streamline and automate; you're just scratching the surface.

Comment: @TedWrigley thank you very much if you can provide an answer. Yeah, I know that by using applescript (coding), it can achieve many actions. So far, selecting file(s) after pasting is enough for me. :)

Comment: Please don‘t add answers/solutions to the question, upvote answers or post one on your own instead.

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the comment. But they are just workarounds instead of a true solution. I posted in the question and hopefully that will help people with the same question. Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Finder to select newly added files using a Folder Action. First, open Script Editor and add the following code to a new Script window:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    tell application "Finder"
        select added_items
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Save this script in the folder `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts`, using whatever name strikes you as convenient (I'll use 'Select Script' for demo purposes).

Second, use spotlight to find and open the Folder Actions Setup app. This is a small helper app hidden way down in the file system (`/System/Library/CoreServices`) that sets up Folder Actions. You'll see a window that looks something like this:

[image]

Use the '+' button on the bottom left to choose a folder you want to attach the action to, then select the desired Folder Action script in the resulting popup menu. The result will look something like this:

[image]

Adding items to this folder will now cause the Finder to open a Finder Window and select the added files. Repeat the second step for every folder you want this behavior to occur in. There's no simple way to get the Finder to automatically do this for every folder (it is possible, but it's a PITA).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail steps and answer. I have upvoted it. But since I have to add each folder in `Folder Actions Setup.app` to make the script work for that specific folder. This is really something I don't want to do. I will rather use sort-by-date-added workaround.

Comment: If that's your preference, you might look into using tags. For instance, you could label all the files in a given folder with colored or named tags for different purposes, and then sort by tags. Freshly added items will be untagged, and be grouped together at the top of the folder. This would give you more flexibility (e.g., allowing you to tag files differently depending on what has been or needs to be done to them). Of course, you have to remember to tag files as/after you process them, but... If it helps!

Comment: I suppose you could even write a background script that would tag files in a folder hierarchy, but you'd have to be a lot clearer about your workflow for anyone to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I may use paste action for the entire file system, not for some specific folders. Tagging all files is not an option either. This is the same as using Folder Actions Setup.app while adding each individual folder. What I want is a general solution which allows me to achieve on all folders. Tagging all files in `/` is something too much.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not mind investing a few minutes, you can open **Automator.app** and create a new **Quick Action** document.

[image]

Next, add a **Run AppleScript** command to the workflow and add this following **AppleScript** code.

```
activate
set destinationFolder to (choose folder with prompt ¬
    "Choose The Destination Folder" default location ¬
    (path to desktop) with invisibles)

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set theFiles to selection as alias list
    set duplicatedFiles to duplicate theFiles ¬
        to destinationFolder with replacing and exact copy
    reveal duplicatedFiles
end tell
```

[image]

Next, save your new Automator Quick Action and name it “Reveal Duplicated Files”

Now, anytime you want to duplicate the currently selected files in Finder to another folder then have them revealed snd selected in the new location, just Right Click the Selected files you want to copy and choose Quick Actions/Reveal Duplicated Files.  This will open a “Choose Folder” dialog , allowing you to choose the folder where the duplicated files will go.  Your files will now be copied to that chosen folder then revealed.

[image]

**NOTE:** The AppleScript code as it is right now, will overwrite any files of the same name, that are currently in the destination folder.